# How to mock local object property which is been set in another method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, mutation-testing

I have similar to below code in my application.

```
public String someMethod(final Object obj) {
    final ValidationResponse validationResponse = new ValidationResponse();
    String responseMessage = validatorService.validate(obj, validationResponse);
    if(validationResponse.isValid()) {
        //Positive flow
    }
    else {
        //Negative flow
    }
    return responseMessage;
}
```

I am writing JUnit test cases to generate Mutation's report. As the object **validationResponse** is used which is a local object created in the flow. Mockito is unable to get & return desired value for **isValid**. Due to this I am unable to cover the test cases for the **Positive flow**.

How this could be achieved? Any lead is very much appreciated.

Comment: Where does `validator1` come from? If anything needs mocking here, it is this object.

Comment: validator1 is some another service whose method isvalidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem from one of my teammate. It is as below

```
Mockito.doNothing(invocation ->
{
    ValidationResponse validationResponse = invocation.getArgument(0);
    validationResponse.setValida(true);//Set value true or false based on the mock test case scenario.
    return null;
})
.when(validatorService)
.validate(obj, validationResponse));
```

This mocks the value of the validation response property.

Answer (score 0):

The flow of this method is determined by this line

```
 String response = validator1.validate(obj, validationResponse);
```

If you want to excercise both branches of the following if statment you need to control the modification that `validator1` makes to the validationResponse object.

This can be done in two ways.

If your test can inject the instance of `validator1` (eg via the code under tests constructor) then you can fake it.

This is probably easiest to do with a hand coded implementation rather than a mocking framework.

eg

```java
class AlwaysInvalid implements WhateverTheTypeOfValidator1Is {
    void validate(Object unused, ValidationResponse response) {
       response.setInvalidOrWhatever();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use a real collaborator, in which case your tests needs to ensure that objects are passed into `someMethod` that result in both valid and invalid responses.